# how to add same y-values (from a cell) for different x values (dynamic) in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro to plot graph for various dates. e.g. expenses for last 1 week. I want to draw a horizontal line in my chart/graph which should show the ideal expense (value provided by me in a cell). as the dates are dynamically changing and the vlue of the ideal expense is present in one cell, I am not sure how to create this series in my chart using VBA.

Comment: `I have written a macro to plot graph for various dates` **show your code**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, where you increase the array size to the scale of the chart and set myIdealRange to the cell that you mentioned?

```
mychart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
mychart.SeriesCollection(mychart.SeriesCollection.Count).Name = "=""ideal"""
mychart.SeriesCollection(mychart.SeriesCollection.Count).Values = Array(myIdealRange, myIdealRange, myIdealRange, myIdealRange, myIdealRange)
mychart.SeriesCollection(mychart.SeriesCollection.Count).Select
Selection.MarkerStyle = -4142
mychart.SeriesCollection(mychart.SeriesCollection.Count).Trendlines.Add
```